# MySQL, смена кодировки в заполненной бд

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. Учусь ПэХаПэ по книге, в главе MySQL создавалась БД на английском языке. Попробовал методом "UPDATE ... SET" переименовать пару записей на русском. Они пропали. Видимо, они есть, но из-за неправильной кодировки не отображаются. Подумал "Ай, на английском попишу", решил обратно сменить тем же методом - не сменяется, выдает предупреждение, но запись не меняет. Это можно как-то решить, не переделывая заново бд? Можно как-то сменить кодировку в заполненной базе данных? И, еще, будьте добры, скажите, каким образом вообще она меняется еще на этапе создания? Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

а на этапе создания таблицы сразу выбирайте utf8

Answer (score 0):

Сменить кодировку таблицы на UTF-8

```
ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Сменить кодировки всех таблиц в UTF-8, Имя бд: My_DB_for_convert

```
SELECT CONCAT(  'ALTER TABLE `', t.`TABLE_SCHEMA` ,  '`.`', t.`TABLE_NAME` ,  '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;' ) AS sqlcode
FROM  `information_schema`.`TABLES` t
WHERE 1
AND t.`TABLE_SCHEMA` =  'My_DB_for_convert'
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 0 , 90
```